# How do I export display to Android native X server?

Tags: linux

I downloaded Ubuntu precise with Complete Linux Installer which uses VNC by default. Then I found a native X server on Google Play and I'd like to try it. I read somewhere I must export display, but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

when you type "xterm" a terminal should appear inside X

But doesn't work very well, because some x11-Features are not implemented in this Android-Xserver.